# By clicking, organize the blocks in descending and ascending order

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is a list of items that are loaded from the database, what script can use to make a filter that will organize the items in ascending and descending order by clicking the mouse?

For example, by clicking "time" you need to show the shortest time or the best time.

For example, you should attach a code and an image

[image]

```css
  .rating_category_header {
            display: flex;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }

        .rating_category_header--number,
        .rating_category_header--photo,
        .rating_category_header--athlete,
        .rating_category_header--trenings,
        .rating_category_header--time,
        .rating_category_header--distance {
            margin-right: 30px;
        }

        .rating_category_item {
            display: flex;
        }

        .rating_item_result {
            display: flex;
        }

        .rating_item_athlete--number {
            margin-right: 35px;
        }

        .rating_item_result--trenings {
            margin-right: 65px;
        }
        .rating_item_result--time {
            margin-right: 30px;
        }
```

```html
<div class="section_body">
        <div class="rating_category">
            <div class="rating_category_header">
                <div class="rating_category_header--number"><a href="">№</a></div>
                <div class="rating_category_header--trenings"><a href=""><span class="ico_trenings"></span><span>trenings</span></a></div>
                <div class="rating_category_header--time"><a href=""><span class="ico_time"></span><span>time</span></a></div>
                <div class="rating_category_header--distance"><a href=""><span class="ico_map"></span><span>distance</span></a></div>
            </div>
            <div class="rating_category_item">
                <div class="rating_item_athlete">
                    <div class="rating_item_athlete--number">1</div>
                </div>
                <div class="rating_item_result">
                    <div class="rating_item_result--trenings">
                        <strong>830</strong>
                    </div>
                    <div class="rating_item_result--time">
                        <strong class="js-date-duration">00:60:58</strong>
                    </div>
                    <div class="rating_item_result--distance">
                        <strong>800 км</strong>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="rating_category_item">
                <div class="rating_item_athlete">
                    <div class="rating_item_athlete--number">2</div>
                </div>
                <div class="rating_item_result">
                    <div class="rating_item_result--trenings">
                        <strong>300</strong>
                    </div>
                    <div class="rating_item_result--time">
                        <strong class="js-date-duration">1:42:36</strong>
                    </div>
                    <div class="rating_item_result--distance">
                        <strong>600 км</strong>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Are you using an API?

Comment: @HarmandeepSinghKalsi judging by the tags javascript and jquery, probably

Comment: On the client side.

Comment: @Will you need a script in javascript or jquery, I'm new to it.

Comment: You can do either by javascript or jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you can edit the HTML output from the server, you can add data attributes for information you want users to be able to sort. If not, you'll have to fetch and parse the data from the HTML nodes. Let's say you can edit the HTML and store the time in seconds to avoid parsing/converting every time.

Your HTML:

```
<div class="section_body">
  <div class="rating_category">
    <div class="rating_category_header">
      <!-- Add data-sort to determine how to sort -->
      <div class="rating_category_header--number"><a data-sort="number">№</a></div>
      <div class="rating_category_header--trenings"><a data-sort="trenings"><span class="ico_trenings"></span><span>trenings</span></a></div>
      <div class="rating_category_header--time"><a data-sort="time"><span class="ico_time"></span><span>time</span></a></div>
      <div class="rating_category_header--distance"><a data-sort="distance"><span class="ico_map"></span><span>distance</span></a></div>
    </div>
    <!-- Add wrapper -->
    <div class="wrapper">
      <!-- Add data-attributes for each data. Make sure data[name] matches data-sort="[name]" above -->
      <div class="rating_category_item" data-number="1" data-trenings="830" data-time="3658" data-distance="800">
        <div class="rating_item_athlete">
          <div class="rating_item_athlete--number">1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rating_item_result">
          <div class="rating_item_result--trenings">
            <strong>830</strong>
          </div>
          <div class="rating_item_result--time">
            <strong class="js-date-duration">00:60:58</strong>
          </div>
          <div class="rating_item_result--distance">
            <strong>800 км</strong>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Add data-attributes for each data. Make sure data[name] matches data-sort="[name]" above -->
      <div class="rating_category_item" data-number="2" data-trenings="300" data-time="6156" data-distance="600">
        <div class="rating_item_athlete">
          <div class="rating_item_athlete--number">2</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rating_item_result">
          <div class="rating_item_result--trenings">
            <strong>300</strong>
          </div>
          <div class="rating_item_result--time">
            <strong class="js-date-duration">1:42:36</strong>
          </div>
          <div class="rating_item_result--distance">
            <strong>600 км</strong>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Using jquery, your script would look like this:

```
// Assumes data-number is your ID and unique
// Places order (asc/desc) and type outside function to change order on second click
$(function(){
  var order, sortBy;
  $(".rating_category_header a").click(function(){
  
    // Check how we should sort the data
    var selectedSortBy = $(this).data("sort");
    // If new filter, do asc, otherwise the opposite of previously sorted
    if (sortBy == null || selectedSortBy != sortBy) {
        order = "asc";
      sortBy = selectedSortBy;
    } else {
      order = order == "asc"? "desc" : "asc";
    }

    var itemsArray = [];
    $(".rating_category_item").each(function(){
      var number = $(this).data("number");
      var data = $(this).data(sortBy);
      // Store in array the ID of the element and the data to sort by
      itemsArray.push([number, data, $(this)]);
    });
    itemsArray.sort(function(a,b) {
      // Sorts second column
      if (order == "asc") return a[1] - b[1];
      else return b[1] - a[1];
    });

    // Empty wrapper and add elements from the sorted array
    $(".wrapper").empty();
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < itemsArray.length; i++) {
      $(".wrapper").append(itemsArray[i][2]);
    }
  })
})
```

Working example here: https://jsfiddle.net/gwL2z0s5/

You may also want to add an indicator next to the sorted field (some sort of triangle showing the order asc/desc) to avoid confusion when the user clicks on a field to sort it while the elements are already in order although they were sorted by another type of data.

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript reverse method.

I've created a simple snippet.

```js
var numbers = [1,2,3,4,5]
var button = document.getElementById('reverseBtn')
var list = document.getElementById('array')

button.addEventListener('click', function(){
    list.innerHTML = ''
    numbers.reverse()
    renderList()
})

var renderList = function(){numbers.forEach((key)=>{
    list.innerHTML += '<div class="rating_item_result--time"><strong class="js-date-duration">' + key + '</strong></div>'
})
}

renderList()
```

```html
<div id="array"></div>
    <button id="reverseBtn">click to reverse</button>
```

Comment: The data is output from the database, so this solution is not exactly suitable, but thank you.

Comment: How are you rendering the elements? Are you looping through a list?

Comment: The list is formed from a database, it is necessary to sort the list "time", "number", "distance" and so on from the client's side.

Comment: I'm working with tables all day every day. When you render tables you have to loop through the array of rows, then render whatever html wrapper you want around that data. Also since you're using jQuery, you might wanna take a look at https://datatables.net/. The company I work for uses this. It has sorting included. It'll save you a whole bunch of time. Good luck! 